# Create SelectOneMenu UIComponent from Server side

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have created a SelectOneMenu uicomponent

```
SelectOneMenu value = new SelectOneMenu();
```

I want to insert some selectItems in the SelectOneMenu.
I tried this

```
String[] options = question.getOptions().split(",");
for(String option : options){
    SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem();
    selectItem.setLabel(option);
    selectItem.setValue(option);
    value.getChildren().add(selectItem);
}
```

But when i add the selectItem i am getting error that add(uicomponent) is not applicable for arguments SelectItem. What to do, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it's failing because [`javax.faces.model.SelectItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html) is not a `UIComponent`. What you should have is the [`UISelectItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UISelectItem.html). So your code should look more like

```
    String[] options = question.getOptions().split(",");
for(String option : options){
    UISelectItem selectItem = new UISelectItem();
    selectItem.setItemLabel(option);
    selectItem.setItemValue(option);
    value.getChildren().add(selectItem);
}
```